# Gentoo server time issue, can't manually set time, NTPD won't correct, too big of a time difference

Tags: time, ntp, gentoo, ntpd

So, my server is living in the future, unfortunately I can't get lottery numbers, or stock picks out of it.

It thinks this is the time: 
`Thu Nov  7 04:07:18 EST 2013`

Not correct, I tried to set the time manually via date in a few ways

`# date -s "06 NOV 2013 14:48:00"`

`# date 110614482013` -- same output, same problem

Which outputs
`Wed Nov  6 14:48:00 EST 2013`, but when I check the date again, it's still set to Nov 7th 0400 or whatever.

I checked my system messages, and I see this pop up often:

`Nov  7 03:54:00 www ntpd[4482]: time correction of -47927 seconds exceeds sanity limit (1000); set clock manually to the correct UTC time.`

Which makes sense, we're way off the correct time. But I can't seem to manually fix it. So now what?

Also, I'm wondering if my hardware clock is setup correct, `hwclock` doesn't return any values. Would that be causing issues?

This is a virtualized server, I don't have direct access to the hypervisor, but I can talk to who does, assume I can explain myself well enough.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried stopping `ntpd`, setting the time manually (or via `ntpdate`), and restarting `ntpd`?

Comment: I think so, but I'll try it again just to be sure, thanks.

Comment: Just tried setting via date, and ntpdate, unfortunately, still stuck 15 hours into the future. @MadHatter

Comment: What kind of hypervisor is it?

Comment: You did stop `ntpd` first, yes?

Comment: Yeah, I stopped it first. I went to check on the hypervisor(xen), that time was wrong too. Setting that correctly, then going back into the server and setting it there seemed to fix it.

Comment: I guess this ended up simpler than I thought, but thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5):

At it's default settings, ntpd will refuse to make any large changes to the system clock, as it assumes something has gone wrong. To force a large NTP update, do the following:

1. Stop the NTPD service
2. run `ntpd -gnqd`
3. Start the NTPD service again

This will cause the NTP daemon to update the time once in the foreground and will allow large time changes.